# Ubuntu 15.04 - Google Chrome official package always fails to install

Tags: google-chrome, dpkg, 15.04

In Ubuntu always the default Google Chrome installation fails. How to fix it.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 176142 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (43.0.2357.65-1) over (43.0.2357.65-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be fixed by running the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with installing `libappindicator1` on Ubuntu and in Docker as well - is installing this package manually. Also, it depends on another one `libindicator7`.

```
RUN curl -p --insecure "http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && curl -p --insecure "http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" --output libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && rm libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && rm libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb
```